# Unobtrusive javascript rendered

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In the wikipedia entry Unobtrusive JavaScript there is an example of obtrusive JavaScript:

```
<input type="text" name="date" onchange="validateDate(this);" />
```

The solution is the following:

```
<input type="text" name="date" />

window.onload = function(){ //Wait for the page to load.
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i=0,l=inputs.length;i<l;i++){ 
        input = inputs[i];
        if(input.name && input.name=='date'){ 
            input.onchange = function(){ 
                validateDate();
            }
        }
    }
};

function validateDate(){
    //Do something when the content of the 'input' element with the name 'date' is changed.
}
```

Is there a way to generate the first code sample from the second?  In other words, is it possible to "render" the HTML of a page after JavaScript has acted on it?

Comment: can you explain in more detail what you're trying to do? I'm not sure what you mean by "render" the html.

Comment: I'm confused too. The two examples are functionally equivalent. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript can be used to render HTML (add elements to the DOM) and this is essentially what the solution does. However if you view the source of the page after the `onchange` event has been added you won't see it - this is because browsers show the unaltered DOM only.

If you want to browse the updated DOM then download [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) for Firefox. I can't recommend this tool enough!

Comment: Yes thank you!  You explained what I was trying to say perfectly.

Comment: The Web Developer toolbar FF extension also have a nice option to "View Generated Source"

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60